# Why is the std::initializer_list constructor preferred when using a braced initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, language-lawyer, list-initialization

Consider the code

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    int val_;
public:
    Foo(std::initializer_list<Foo> il)
    {
        std::cout << "initializer_list ctor" << std::endl;
    }
    /* explicit */ Foo(int val): val_(val)
    {
        std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
    };
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // why is the initializer_list ctor invoked?
    Foo foo {10}; 
}
```

The output is

```
ctor
initializer_list ctor
```

As far as I understand, the value `10` is implicitly converted to a `Foo` (first `ctor` output), then the initializer constructor kicks in (second `initializer_list ctor` output). My question is why is this happening? Isn't the standard constructor `Foo(int)` a better match? I.e., I would have expected the output of this snippet to be just `ctor`.

PS: If I mark the constructor `Foo(int)` as `explicit`, then `Foo(int)` is the only constructor invoked, as the integer `10` cannot now be implicitly converted to a `Foo`.

Comment: I knew it trumps over regular constructors, but didn't know that it trumps even when the regular constructor is a better match. And yes, it seems a bit strange to be this way. Is there any particular reason? In this way, one can hide the copy constructor (actually, the code I have WILL hide the copy constructor, doesn't it?)

Comment: Scott Meyers' new book, "Effective Modern C++" has a very good item about the various initialization styles: "Item 7: Distinguish between () and {} when creating objects". It doesn't give much in the way of the rationale for the behavior, but does go into a lot of detail on some of the edge cases that might surprise you.

Comment: @MichaelBurr thanks, I'm still waiting for a physical copy :)

Comment: I know it's unrelated, but can anyone tell me whether I should have initializer_list by value or by const reference in my constructor ? And what is reason for that ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

§13.3.1.7 [over.match.list]/p1:

> When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized
>   (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> - Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class `T` and the argument list consists of
>     the initializer list as a single argument.
> - If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all
>     the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of
>     the elements of the initializer list.
>
> If the initializer list has no elements and `T` has a default
>   constructor, the first phase is omitted. In copy-list-initialization,
>   if an `explicit` constructor is chosen, the initialization is
>   ill-formed.

As long as there is a viable initializer-list constructor, it will trump all non-initializer-list constructors when list-initialization is used and the initializer list has at least one element.

Comment: Ok, +1, I think this nails it! For some reason I thought that init_list ctors won't trump if conversions are needed, but it doesn't seem to be the case. But, if this is the case, then the code I have seem to be hiding a potential copy constructor, doesn't it? As copy ctor will just copy the parameter for the init list ctor, and the latter can do whatever I desire.

Comment: @vsoftco Well, this rule applies only if you are using list-initialization. When you don't use `{}` the copy ctor will be called just fine. An implicit special member function can indeed be "hidden". A common case is a template constructor taking a single forwarding reference argument optionally followed by a pack (e.g., `template<class T> Foo(T&&)`), which is usually a better match than a copy ctor taking a `const Foo &`.

Comment: @vsoftco, the code you have is only hiding a potential copy because you have `Foo(std::initializer_list<Foo>)` which makes no sense to me. What is that constructor for? Anyway, if you use a non-empty braced-init-list and there is an initializer-list constructor, it will be used, even if that requires an array of `Foo` objects to be created to bind the `std::initializer_list` to.

Comment: @JonathanWakely this was just a toy example, as I was trying to understand how `std::initializer_list` constructor works. I'm not using it in reality :)

Answer (score 15):

The [n2100](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2100.pdf) proposal for initializer lists goes into great detail about the decision to make sequence constructors (what they call constructors that take `std::initializer_lists`) to have priority over regular constructors. See Appendix B for a detailed discussion. It's succinctly summarized in the conclusion:

> 11.4 Conclusion
>
> So, how do we decide between the remaining two alternatives (“ambiguity” and “sequence constructors take priority
>   over ordinary constructors)? Our proposal gives sequence constructors
>   priority because
>
> - Looking for ambiguities among all the constructors leads to too many “false positives”; that is, clashes between apparently unrelated
>     constructors. See examples below.
> - Disambiguation is itself error-prone (as well as verbose). See examples in §11.3.
> - Using exactly the same syntax for every number of elements of a homogeneous list is important – disambiguation should be done for
>     ordinary constructors (that do not have a regular pattern of
>     arguments). See examples in §11.3. The simplest example of a false
>     positive is the default constructor:
>
> The simplest example of a false positive is the default constructor:
>
> ```
> vector<int> v; 
> vector<int> v { }; // potentially ambiguous
> void f(vector<int>&); 
> // ...
> f({ }); // potentially ambiguous
> ```
>
> It is possible to think of classes where initialization with no
>   members is semantically distinct from default initialization, but we
>   wouldn’t complicate the language to provide better support for those
>   cases than for the more common case where they are semantically the
>   same.
>
> Giving priority to sequence constructors breaks argument checking into
>   more comprehensible chunks and gives better locality.
>
> ```
> void f(const vector<double>&);
> // ...
> struct X { X(int); /* ... */ };
> void f(X);
> // ...
> f(1);     // call f(X); vector’s constructor is explicit
> f({1});   // potentially ambiguous: X or vector?
> f({1,2}); // potentially ambiguous: 1 or 2 elements of vector
> ```
>
> Here, giving priority to sequence constructors eliminates the
>   interference from X. Picking X for f(1) is a variant of the problem
>   with explicit shown in §3.3.

Answer (score 5):

The whole initializer list thing was meant to enable list initialisation like so:

```
std::vector<int> v { 0, 1, 2 };
```

Consider the case

```
std::vector<int> v { 123 };
```

That this initializes the vector with one element of value 123 rather than 123 elements of value zero is intended.

To access the other constructor, use the old syntax

```
Foo foo(10);
```

Comment: This makes sense, as both `initialzier_list` and regular ctors take `int` as parameters. I was surprised that even when a conversion is needed in the `initializer_list` ctor, the latter is still preferred.

Comment: @seldon is the "old syntax" the only way to excape from the `initializer_list`. I mean, is it the standard way?