# Direct list initialization, which constructor will be used?

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list, list-initialization

Recently, I found a bug in my code due to the use of "modern" 'direct list initialization' syntax. The gist of the issue looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{   
    std::cout << std::string(static_cast<std::size_t>(2), 'y');
    std::cout << std::string{static_cast<std::size_t>(2), 'x'};

    return 0;
}
```

With the following compilation command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp && ./a.out | xxd
```

I get the following result:

```
00000000: 7979 0278                                yy.x
```

Where we can see that the strings were not initialized in the same way. The first one use the `fill` string constructor which repeat the char `'y'` twice. But for the second one, it seems the braces are interpreted as a `std::initializer_list<char>`, hence the `0x02` in the binary output.

Both `g++` and `clang++` produce the same behavior, so I suppose this is to be expected.

The question is then, how do I know if/when my braces are interpreted as an argument list for a constructor or as a single `std::initializer_list` ?

Comment: My rule of thumb (even though it is 100% accurate), `{}` is always list initialization.  If you don't want a list, use `()` instead.

Comment: The second initialization is [*list* initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), not [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Indeed but in the list-initialization link you provide, they say "both explicit and non-explicit constructors are considered" so why doesn't it default on the same one ? Is there a way to know ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude While it is list initialization, it is actually direct list initialization, which is considered direct initialization: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#16

Comment: Well I think I've found my answer reading a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18224556/2312686

"The `initializer_list<>` constructor is preferred to the other constructors"

Comment: Unfortunately for you `static_cast<std::size_t>(2)` is a valid constexpr literal for `char` (and so no narrowing error).

Comment: Maybe someone could mark it as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/27144054/2312686 (I think I cannot). What is strange though here is that the `static_cast` doesn't help. <- Thanks @Jarod42

Comment: @NathanOliver If I read [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) correctly, case (2) is about "object of **non-class** type" and it adds "(note: for class types and other uses of braced-init-list, see list-initialization)" too.

Comment: @Jarod42 Is this duplicate really sufficient to answer the question? For me, your comment is as important as the information contains in the duplicate.

Comment: @Holt I proposed the duplicate but I'm not a SO power user so I will gladly let you debate it. ;) Maybe there is a question somewhere about implicit cast of literals, there is then a combinatorics computation to determine the number of valid questions from the number of "atomic" topics.