# c++ how to initialize vector from variadic pack?

Tags: c++, vector, variadic-templates, size-t

I have a templated `Container` storing values in `vector`. There is no problem with `string`s or `int`s, but `size_t` values don't compile. It seems the compiler assumes I want to initialize the `vector` with `int`s instead of `size_t` values. How can I solve this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class ValueType>
class Container {
public:
    template <typename... ValueTypes>
    Container(ValueTypes&&... values) :
        currentIndex(0),
        values{ std::forward<ValueTypes>(values)... }
    {}

    const ValueType operator()() const {
        return values[currentIndex];
    }

protected:
    size_t currentIndex;
    std::vector<ValueType> values;
};

int main() {
    Container<std::string> container1("10", "20", "30");    // ok
    Container<int> container2(10, 20, 30);                  // ok
    Container<size_t> container3(10, 20, 30);               // compile error, assumed ints!
}
```

Comment: i see only a warning https://godbolt.org/z/GqYsW83q5

Comment: How about `Container<size_t> container3(10ULL, 20ULL, 30ULL);` ?

Comment: you can use a 'u' suffix. https://godbolt.org/z/f7ToxsbsM

Comment: Error C2398 Element '1': conversion from '_Ty' to '_Ty' requires a narrowing conversion

Answer (score 4):

These are two methods to choose from (second one is more typesafe but requires a slightly different syntax to use)..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <class type_t>
class Container {
public:
    

    // Constructor 1
    template <typename... args_t>
    Container(args_t&&... args) :
        m_currentIndex{}
    {
        // pre alocate memory to avoid resizing
        m_values.reserve(sizeof...(args_t));

        // use a fold expression to put all values in the vector
        (m_values.emplace_back(std::forward<args_t>(args)),...);
    }

    // Constructor 2, more typesafe
    template<std::size_t N>
    Container(const type_t (&values)[N]) :
        m_values{std::begin(values),std::end(values)}
    {
    }

    // return a const& here so you avoid a copy
    const type_t& operator()() const 
    {
        return m_values[m_currentIndex];
    }

protected:
    size_t m_currentIndex;
    std::vector<type_t> m_values;
};

int main() 
{
    // Constructor 1
    Container<std::string> container1{"10", "20", "30"};    // ok
    Container<int> container2{10, 20, 30};                  // ok
    Container<size_t> container3{10, 20, 30};               // ok

    // Constructor 2
    Container<std::string> container4{{"10", "20", "30"}};    // ok
    Container<int> container5{{10, 20, 30}};                  // ok
    Container<size_t> container6{{10, 20, 30}};               // ok
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`10`, `20` and `30` are indeed `int` literals, so the narrowing conversion error/warning is expected.

You can use a `u` (or `ULL`) suffix to make them literals compliant with `size_t` (which is unsigned):

```
Container<size_t> container3(10u, 20u, 30u);
```

Comment: Thanks. But how it is possible that std::vector<size_t> v{10, 20, 30} works without problem? The compiler assumes size_t here without any suffix...

Comment: @MiroslavKrajcir I've explained in great detail why `std::vector<size_t> v{10, 20, 30}` works in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72505254/12002570)

Comment: Another option would be `size_t(10)` - I agree that a `u` suffix is the better option, but just mentioning an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

The **problem** is that  `values` is not a constant expression(since it is a function parameter) and so the conversion from `values` to `size_t` is a narrowing conversion.

This can be seen from [dcl.init.list#7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#7) which states:

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, **except where the source is a constant expression** whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type.

(emphasis mine)

Basically,  this has the same reason as why `std::vector<size_t> v{10, 20, 30}` will work but `int i = 0; std::vector<size_t> v{i, 20, 30};` will not work. Similarly, `const int i = 0; std::vector<size_t> v{i, 20, 30};` will work.

```
std::vector<size_t> v{10, 20, 30}; //ok because 10, 20 and 30 all are constant expressions

int i = 0; //i is not a constant expression
std::vector<size_t> v{i, 20, 30}; //not ok because i is not a constant  expression and so narrowing conversion

const int  j= 0; //j is a constant expression 
std::vector<size_t> v{j, 20, 30}; //ok because j is a constant expression
```

---

One way to solve this is to explicitly write suffix `U` to each of the literals.

```
Container<size_t> container3(10U, 20U, 30U);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can forward `ValueTypes` to construct the actual `ValueType`, so that the `std::vector<ValueType>` is constructed via `std::initializer_list<ValueType>`

```
template <typename... ValueTypes>
Container(ValueTypes&&... values) :
    currentIndex(0),
    values{ ValueType(std::forward<ValueTypes>(values))... }
{}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/onT9q716o)