# Why is the conversion to int picked over the conversion to vector<int>

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

```
struct A
{
    A(std::vector<int> x):
    x_(std::move(x)) {}

    inline operator std::vector<int>()
    {
        return x_;
    }

    inline operator int()
    {
        return x_[0];
    }
    std::vector<int> x_;
};

A add()
{
    return A({1,2,3,4});
}



int main()
{
    std::vector<int> b{add()};
}
```

In the code above, `b` will have only 1 element, which means the conversion `A->int` is picked over `A->vector<int>`. Why is that?

Is it because at the formation of initializer_list, both conversion works so it picks the one `A->int`?

Comment: You only have one constructor, and there is no overload to pick for your conversion operatorions since you don't call it (your code is incomplete). Side not always make your constructors with one argument `explicit`.

Comment: See the detailed explanation given in this post's answer: [Why can't I initialize this std::vector with an l-value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72505009/why-cant-i-initialize-this-stdvector-with-an-l-value/). I think that should explain this?

Comment: Note that you don't need `add` here at all. You can just do `std::vector<int> b{A({1,2,3,4})};` and the program will have same behavior as in your code. [Reduced demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cYjd3n633)

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` has a constructor that accepts a `std::initialize_list`. When a class has such a constructor, that overload will always be chosen when brace initialization is used, if possible. It is possible in this case, if `add()`'s result is converted to `int`, so it is. If you try `std::vector<int> b(add());` you will get a copy of the result of `add()` instead : https://godbolt.org/z/8TqMEfeYf