# Best practice to stop initialiser list constructor from taking priority

Tags: c++

I have created a minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
class Vector {
    private:
        size_t sz;
        double* elem;
    public:
        Vector(size_t s) : sz{s}, elem{new double[s]} {}
        Vector(std::initializer_list<double> lst) : sz{lst.size()}, elem{new double[lst.size()]} {
            std::copy(lst.begin(), lst.end(), elem);
        }
        size_t size() const {return sz;}
        double& operator[](size_t i) {
            if (i < 0 || i >= sz)
                throw std::out_of_range("Vector::operator[](size_t): index out of range");
    
            return elem[i];
        }
};

int main() {
    Vector v1{3};
    Vector v2{v1.size()};
    std::cout << v2[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << v2[1] << '\n';
}
```

When I compile, I get the warning: `problem.cpp:25:22: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘v1.Vector::size()’ from ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} to ‘double’`. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144054/why-is-the-stdinitializer-list-constructor-preferred-when-using-a-braced-initi) question (thanks @Joel for the reference), this is because list initializer constructors take precedence. I can see this when I run the code, as I get the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  Vector::operator[](size_t): index out of range
```

Clearly, both `v1` and `v2` are constructed as single element vectors, so calling `v2[1]` makes no sense.
Although I've identified the problem, the question I was referred to doesn't solve it fully. My question would be: is there a recommended way to get past such behaviour? Is `()` initialisation the way? However, this somewhat defeats the purpose of uniform initialisation. Or should I set some of my constructors as `explicit`? Or is there another standard way to circumvent this feature?

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: By the way: `if (s < 0) throw(...)` *[`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) is the **unsigned** integer type of the result of sizeof , _Alignof (since C11) and offsetof, depending on the data model.* This means that this expression will always evaluate to false so this check is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uniform initialization is fundamentally broken in this regard. Even if you fix your custom container, the standard ones will forever have this issue.

IMO, there's no benefit in using it everywhere. If you're worried about implicit conversions, `-Wconversion` (or your compiler's equivalent) will catch them better than uniform initialization possibly could.

But if you want to embrace it for your class, you can use tag dispatch (aka an extra unused empty struct parameter):

```
struct WithSize {};
```

```
Vector(WithSize, size_t s) : sz{s}, elem{new double[s]} {}
```

Then `Vector v1{3};` will produce a single-element vector, while `Vector v1{WithSize{}, 3};` would give you 3 zeroes.

> Or should I set some of my constructors as explicit?

`std::vector`'s `(size_t)` constructor is `explicit`, which at least makes the `= {...}` syntax safe in this regard (it'll always call the `initializer_list` constructor, never falling back to the size constructor). But that's a different issue, it doesn't help with yours.

If you use a tag dispatch as suggested, there's no point adding `explicit`.